# My 4T disk with ext4 does not work for more than 5 minutes

Tags: filesystem

I got a WD large drive, 4T with USB enclosure (powered by a dedicated AC adapter). I formatted it in my laptop (Ubuntu 12.04) as a single ext4 file system without any partition.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
```

something like this command line, anyway, it works fine in my Ubuntu. Then I  mounted the drive on my raspberry PI (version 1). The whole disk is mounted without any warning and I published the volume with Samba. When I was testing the disk by playing a movie that was copied to the disk, the video stopped on the first several minutes, no more than 5 minutes.

What could be the reason that makes the file system un-stable?

Please ask me if you need any more detail to diagnose. Thanks!

I reproduced the problem today, and compared the system-log between before and after, shown as below. Also compared the dmesg output.

```
--- system-1.log    2015-03-25 21:46:13.561099557 +0800
+++ system-3.log    2015-03-25 22:12:00.807178794 +0800
@@ -930,3 +930,52 @@
 Mar 25 21:44:05 raspberrypi ntpd[2452]: restrict: error in address '::1' on line 42. Ignoring...
 Mar 25 21:45:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2519]: (pi) CMD (   date >> /home/pi/.local/heart-beat.log)
 Mar 25 21:45:14 raspberrypi kernel: [  112.544267] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
+Mar 25 21:50:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2556]: (pi) CMD (   date >> /home/pi/.local/heart-beat.log)
+Mar 25 21:55:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2561]: (pi) CMD (   date >> /home/pi/.local/heart-beat.log)
+Mar 25 22:00:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2578]: (pi) CMD (   date >> /home/pi/.local/heart-beat.log)
+Mar 25 22:03:48 raspberrypi rpc.mountd[2154]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting.
+Mar 25 22:03:48 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1226.725949] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
+Mar 25 22:03:51 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1228.973047] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
+Mar 25 22:03:51 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1228.973182] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net c05f7c50)
+Mar 25 22:03:51 raspberrypi rpc.mountd[2709]: Version 1.2.6 starting
+Mar 25 22:04:51 raspberrypi rpc.mountd[2709]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.1.253:42416 for /mnt/disk (/mnt/disk)
+Mar 25 22:05:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2728]: (pi) CMD (   date >> /home/pi/.local/heart-beat.log)
+Mar 25 22:07:41 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1459.866541] usb 1-1.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.202113] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213123] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213160] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213173] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213187] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB:
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213196] cdb[0]=0x88: 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 62 18 00 00 00 f0 00 00
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213252] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2449944
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213659] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213682] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213693] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213706] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB:
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213718] cdb[0]=0x88: 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 63 08 00 00 00 f0 00 00
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.213764] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2450184
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.228280] Aborting journal on device sdb-8.
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.228355] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdb-8.
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.228424] journal commit I/O error
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.522003] usb 1-1.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.623395] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2537, idProduct=1066
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.623429] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.623445] usb 1-1.3.3: Product: HE-G130(NS1066 2.45)
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.623459] usb 1-1.3.3: Manufacturer: SSK
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.623474] usb 1-1.3.3: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABE79
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.630003] usb-storage 1-1.3.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
+Mar 25 22:07:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1465.635440] scsi2 : usb-storage 1-1.3.3:1.0
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.162303] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD40EZRX-22S 0A80 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.165920] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.166410] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.166433] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.167085] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.167119] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.167798] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.170227] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.195672]  sdc: unknown partition table
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.197268] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.199044] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.657898] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
+Mar 25 22:07:49 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1467.658640] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
+Mar 25 22:10:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2761]: (pi) CMD (   date >> /home/pi/.local/heart-beat.log)
```

---------- dmesg.diff ----

```
--- dmesg.log   2015-03-25 21:47:28.608906645 +0800
+++ dmesg-2.log 2015-03-25 22:19:53.323958529 +0800
@@ -245,3 +245,44 @@
 [   35.093166] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net c05f7c50)
 [   37.453304] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:3 across:106492k FS
 [  112.544267] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
+[ 1226.725949] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
+[ 1228.973047] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
+[ 1228.973182] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net c05f7c50)
+[ 1459.866541] usb 1-1.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
+[ 1465.202113] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
+[ 1465.213123] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
+[ 1465.213160] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]
+[ 1465.213173] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
+[ 1465.213187] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB:
+[ 1465.213196] cdb[0]=0x88: 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 62 18 00 00 00 f0 00 00
+[ 1465.213252] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2449944
+[ 1465.213659] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
+[ 1465.213682] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]
+[ 1465.213693] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
+[ 1465.213706] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB:
+[ 1465.213718] cdb[0]=0x88: 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 63 08 00 00 00 f0 00 00
+[ 1465.213764] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2450184
+[ 1465.228280] Aborting journal on device sdb-8.
+[ 1465.228355] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdb-8.
+[ 1465.228424] journal commit I/O error
+[ 1465.522003] usb 1-1.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
+[ 1465.623395] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2537, idProduct=1066
+[ 1465.623429] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
+[ 1465.623445] usb 1-1.3.3: Product: HE-G130(NS1066 2.45)
+[ 1465.623459] usb 1-1.3.3: Manufacturer: SSK
+[ 1465.623474] usb 1-1.3.3: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABE79
+[ 1465.630003] usb-storage 1-1.3.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
+[ 1465.635440] scsi2 : usb-storage 1-1.3.3:1.0
+[ 1467.162303] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD40EZRX-22S 0A80 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
+[ 1467.165920] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
+[ 1467.166410] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)
+[ 1467.166433] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
+[ 1467.167085] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
+[ 1467.167119] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
+[ 1467.167798] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
+[ 1467.170227] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
+[ 1467.195672]  sdc: unknown partition table
+[ 1467.197268] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
+[ 1467.199044] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
+[ 1467.657898] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
+[ 1467.658640] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
```

I also saw some error message in the console:

```
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar 25 22:07:47 ...
kernel:[ 1465.228424] journal commit I/O error
```

Does this mean the journal recording makes the trouble?

Comment: Now, the only thing I know and could try is to create a partition table.

Comment: How are you powering the Drive?

Comment: The USB HDD enclosure has a dedicated power supply, I believe it is powerful enough.

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages relating to the drive in the logs? less /var/log/syslog (arrows to move, Q to quit)

Comment: I paste my system log and dmesg into the post. I am sorry, I did not find anything un-usual.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you make sure that the problem lies with the drive and mounting itself?

   - Did you try SCP/SFTP'ing large files to and from the drive?
   - Does the drive crash any other time. What happens when it crashes?
   - After it crashes, can you access the drive immediately or after sometime / do you have to mount/unmount it again?
   - Have you tried connecting the drive via a powered USB hub?
   - Have you noticed any power fluctuations / power related warnings?
2. Can you make sure the problem is with the file system? Have you tried mounting the drive as NTFS-3g?
3. Have you tried other drives of different brands, specification , size or file system?
   I see I/O errors in the log. I had I/O problems with an old Sony drive myself, so I'm using a newer Seagate 500 GB drive with a powered USB hub and NTFS-3g file system.

**Why you're probably having problems with large drives**

The problem might be happening due to *sector / cluster size allocation*. Use latest Raspbian image. It could also result from an *incompatible HDD enclosure*. Try OpenELEC/Raspbmc and check if you have problems with those distributions.

Comment: * I have just tried the SFTP and found the same problem, the drive crashed after downloading 10% of a 400MB file.

Comment: I have just tried the SFTP and found the same problem, the drive crashed after downloading 10% of a 400MB file. So, I believe the drive always crashes when reading/writing. No, I cannot use it anymore until I reboot my raspberry PI. Cannot mount/umount. Power, already using a dedicated power supply + a powered USB hub. No, power related warning was noticed. The file system is Ext4. I don't think a NTFS-3g would be better, do you mean I should format my drive again with NTFS? Yes, I am using another 160GM drive at the same time. The smaller one works well for several months already.

Comment: This does seem to be a H/W incompatibility issue. I suggest you try another HDD. Had the same trouble with an older Sony HDD myself but no problems with a newer Seagate 500 GB HDD. I have successfully used upto 1 TB HDD's so I can assure you that a new Seagate/ WD/ Hitachi HDD (<= 1 TB) should work just fine. I have heard of people who use 2 TB drives successfully too, but never of 4 TB drives with the RPi. Good Luck.

Comment: HW problem? I would try to mount it in a 64 bit Linux and check it with sFTP/SMB.